# How to background tasks within a bash loop

Tags: bash, loops, background

Given the following bash loop:

```
for ((x=1; x<=$y; x++)); do echo $x; done
1
2
3
4
```

How to "background" the individual tasks?

```
09:25:58/~ $for ((x=1; x<=$y; x++)); do echo $xi &; done
-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

I tried "bash"ing the echo and that did not work either:

```
09:26:37/~ $for ((x=1; x<=$y; x++)); do bash -c "echo $x" &; done
-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Comment: *Both* `&` and `;` are command terminators. You only need *one* per-command.

Comment: @Etan Reisner  your comment is the most useful. Please make an answer of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Both* `&` and `;` are command terminators in the shell.

You only need to terminate each command once. So don't use both together:

```
for ((x=1; x<=$y; x++)); do echo $x & done
```

You would get the same error by using two `;`s as well:

```
$ for ((x=1; x<=$y; x++)); do echo $x ; ; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Note that trying to use `;;` gets a different error because `;;` is a special token to the shell (used in `case` statements):

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
```

[Shell grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10):

> ```
> %start  complete_command
> %%
> complete_command : list separator
>                  | list
>                  ;
> list             : list separator_op and_or
>                  |                   and_or
>                  ;
> ....
> separator_op     : '&'
>                  | ';'
>                  ;
> separator        : separator_op linebreak
>                  | newline_list
>                  ;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
for ((x=1; x<=y; x++)); do echo $x & done
```

Note that there is no `;` after `&`.  However using line breaks will make it more readable:

```
for ((x=1; x<=y; x++)); do
  echo $x &
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ((x=1; x<=$y; x++)); do { echo $x & } ; done
```

Comment: The braces are not necessary.